# How to use `relative_url` inside custom plugin

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I am trying to use `relative_url` filter inside a plugin.

```
module Jekyll
  module Tags
    class MyNewTag < Liquid::Block

      include Jekyll::Filters::URLFilters

      def initialize(tag_name, block_options, liquid_options)
        super
        @class = block_options.strip
      end

      def render(context)

        context.stack do
          context["class"] = @class
          @content = super
          path_js = Jekyll::Filters::URLFilters::relative_url("assets/custom.min.css")
          path_css = Jekyll::Filters::URLFilters::relative_url("assets/custom.min.js")
        end

        output = <<~EOS
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="#{path_js}">
        <script src="#{path_css}"></script>

        EOS
      end
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('MyNewTag', Jekyll::Tags::MyNewTag)
```

However, Ruby shows `NoMethodError: undefined method` relative_url' for Jekyll::Filters::URLFilters:Module` - hence I am not able to use it.

How should I include `relative_url` filter, so that I could use it in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that the error was caused by the lack of context variable, which must be passed explicitly by `@context = context`

It works, if it is formatted this way:

```
module Jekyll
  module Tags
    class MyNewTag < Liquid::Block

      include Jekyll::Filters::URLFilters

      def initialize(tag_name, block_options, liquid_options)
        super
        @class = block_options.strip
      end

      def render(context)

        context.stack do
          context["class"] = @class
          @content = super
          @context = context
          @path_js = relative_url("assets/custom.min.css")
          @path_css = relative_url("assets/custom.min.js")
        end

        output = <<~EOS
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="#{@path_js}">
        <script src="#{@path_css}"></script>

        EOS
      end
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('MyNewTag', Jekyll::Tags::MyNewTag)
```